# HQL how to use sum function for list in entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi everyone I need your help;

How to use Sum function of HQL for a list of an entity OneToMany.

I try to explain my problem via code examples.

Here is my Invoice entity

```
@Entity
public class Invoice extends ExtendedBaseEntity {

@Column(nullable = true,length = 50)
private String invoiceNo;

@Column(nullable = true)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone = "EET")
private Date invoiceDate;

@Column(nullable = true,precision = 10,scale = 2)
private BigDecimal amount; getters and setters.....
```

And here is my File entity.This entity hold an Invoice list OneTOMany

```
@Entity    
public class File extends ExtendedBaseEntity {
@Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
private String surname;

@Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
private String lawyerCode;

@Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
private String sellerCode;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "MBSFILE_OID")
private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>(); setters and getters ....
```

and here is my hql, I want to Sum(invoice.amount). But query didn't work as through, I got a wrong results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            SUM(invoice.amount) AS totalAmount
FROM file 
LEFT JOIN file.invoices AS invoice
```

How can I cope with this? Could you help me,please?

Comment: well you need a `GROUP BY` statement

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much I handled it.